# How Can I Make Dropdownlist act like a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, textbox, dropdownlistfor

I Want to make some dropdownlist act like a textbox without losing the ability to explore the list and i want the list to autoselect the list item that match the text in the textbox (Searchable DropDownList).

if the text didn't match any list item i want to insert this value into a lookup table.

I'm using the AutoCompeleteExtender in other textboxes but with this extender the user unable to open the list and select a specific item.

if there is a better practice i'll be glad to know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally recommend the `Select2` plugin, I have been using this in most of my project which have the same requirement as you have.

`Select2` gives you a customizable select box with support for searching, tagging, remote data sets, infinite scrolling, and many other highly used options.

[Select2 Main Site](https://select2.github.io/)

[Select2 Examples Page](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the searchable dropdownlist part, you can use [this](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plug-in. This plug-in also enables you to get the keywords that didn't match any list item